# Blurry text in WPF only when the program is ran

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have been having this issue with blurry text in WPF. I know that there are these `TextFormatting="Display"` options and I've been googling a lot, but the thing is that it's still not right. Let me demonstrate:

[image: WPF blurry text]

The left side is what I see in Visual Studio 2011 Developer Preview's "preview mode", and the right side is what I see when I actually run the program. What I want is the left ClearType which is by far the nicest, but none of those options in actual program running mode look good.

This is the code:

```xml
<StackPanel TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
    <TextBlock>Hello World ... ClearType</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Grayscale">Hello World ... Grayscale</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased">Hello World ... Aliased</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

How do I render text the way it is rendered in the preview mode right inside Visual Studio?

**EDIT**: I found out that the reason that causes this problem is because I use [WPF Shell Integration Library](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell) with the Glass style. This glass style somehow makes WPF to not use ClearType.

Comment: What version of WPF do you use?

Comment: How do I find out? Project properties say target framework is `.NET Framework 4.5 Client Profile`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try writing the following way:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="ClearType ENABLED." RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"/>
```

You can read about ClearTypeHint at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.cleartypehint.aspx)

Comment: Woah that did it! Now can I somehow apply that to the whole window, because I have tabs, grids and lots of content with text?

Comment: Try setting it in `<Window ... >` element

Comment: Read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2009/10/28/new-wpf-features-cleartypehint.aspx it has more info about how this property works, maybe it's appllyible to your case

Comment: @rFactor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228311/flowdocument-loses-cleartype-in-child-elements-when-placed-in-window-with-custom this question can alsow help